# Using wordpress as admin interface for a search web application

Tags: solr, wordpress, backend

I am doing research regarding the development of a search web application.

The main purpose will be to allow users to search in a big list of entities (let's assume they are products), that refer to external websites.

Additionally, there will be articles grouped into categories, mostly separated from the search functionality and search results.

I am probably going to use Apache Solr as search backend.

My question now is, should I write the administration interface/backend completely myself, or should I use some CMS, to reuse an already existing administration interface and underlying infrastructure?

The main tasks for the editors/admins are

- Create / edit / archive articles
- Create / edit searchable product entries (that need to get indexed by Solr)

Is it (relatively) easy to create and manage database entities that have nothing to do with Wordpress from within the WP Admin interface? Does that mean I would need create my own plugin?

Comment: I used WP many times as admin-only with Flash front-ends, it's quite easy to load a minimum WP and extract information using its default functions. Research [WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for more info in this "light loading".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom taxonomy with recent WordPress, so yes you can create non-article stuff and decide how it gets exposed.

You do need to figure out how to get Solr to search your WordPress content, perhaps a plugin such as [Solr for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/solr-for-wordpress/) or [Advanced search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-search-by-my-solr-server/) (did not test either myself). But you need to make sure that the plugin can work with a custom taxonomy (not sure if the first one does).

Alternative, if you are not stuck with WordPress, you can look at systems that integrate Solr as one of their features, such as with [Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) or [OpenCMS](http://www.opencms.org/en/news/120924-opencms-v85.html).

Comment: The thing is, I have developed my own webapps (mostly in Java/Grails), but so far was only a Wordpress user. I'm unsure what the learning curve in reusing functionality of a CMS would be, compared to developing everything from scratch myself. - So no, I'm not stuck with WordPress. Researching some more, Drupal seems to be the choice as framework for more "enterprise" or "serious" web apps, compared to WordPress.

Comment: If you are mostly a Java programmer, I do not recommend starting with Drupal - it has quite a high learning curve. So, OpenCMS or other Java solution is better for that. Or custom code - but that's the choice only you can make. Basic Solr integration is quite simple either way. Especially if you do full-reindex and ignore partial update issues (a perfectly fine option to start with).